# For loop giving different results for user-entered list vs a hard coded list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically I have dictionary with each key-pair having its value as a list. Reason, is so that I can insert or append additional values into the list later on.

Like this, each key pair is:

```
'A' : [2]
```

To make testing code faster, I hard coded a portion of the playerDict like this:

```
playerDict = {"A" : [2], "B" : [2], "C" : [2]}
```

I also allowed a way to enter additional key-pairs. So I can manually enter additional key-pair 'D' and 'E'

```
{'A': [2], 'B': [2], 'C': [2], 'D': [2], 'E': [2]}
```

Looks exactly the same when I print out the playerDict. However, behaviour is different when I run it through a for loop to insert/append values into the list.

```
{'A': [2, 5, 1, 4], 'B': [2, 6, 5, 1], 'C': [2, 6, 5, 1], 'D': [2, 8, 6, 1, 5, 5, 3], 'E': [2, 8, 6, 1, 5, 5, 3]}
```

Behaviour for A, B and C is what I want, which is only 1 insertion at index 1 of the list and 2x appending at the end of the list for each key-pair.

However, for the manually entered key-pair, it gets inserted and appended how many times I manually placed a key-pair in. Place in 2 key-pair, 2 times, place in 3 key-pair, it gets inserted and appended 3 times.

```
{'A': [2, 6, 2, 4], 'B': [2, 3, 1, 2], 'C': [2, 6, 4, 2], 'D': [2, 9, 10, 11, 5, 6, 4, 6,6, 3], 'E': [2, 9, 10, 11, 5, 6, 4, 6, 6, 3], 'F': [2, 9, 10, 11, 5, 6, 4, 6, 6, 3]}
```

Its driving me nuts since I'm unsure what is the difference between my hard-coded key-pairs and the manually entered ones. How can I get my desired behaviour?

```
import random

def rollDice():
  return random.randint(1, 6)

def getPlayers(playerDict):

  points = [2]
  while True:
    name = str(input("Enter player name, <Enter> to end: "))

    if name == "":
      break
    else:
      playerDict[name] = points
      print(playerDict, "adding a user")
  return playerDict

def startGame(playerDict):
  print("Start game. Roll 2 dice per player")

  for names, stats in playerDict.items():
    rollstart1 = rollDice()
    rollstart2 = rollDice()
    total = rollstart1 + rollstart2

    stats.insert(1, total)
    stats.append(rollstart1)
    stats.append(rollstart2)
    print("{}, dice: ({}, {}), total {}".format(names, stats[2], stats[3], stats[1]))
  return playerDict

def main():

  #playerDict = {}
  playerDict = {"A" : [2], "B" : [2], "C" : [2]}

  playerDict = getPlayers(playerDict)
  playerDict = startGame(playerDict)
  print(playerDict)

main()
```

Comment: All of the non-default players share the *exact same `points` list*. Just make it `playerDict[name] = [2]`, it's unclear why you initialised it outside of the loop to begin with.

Comment: So what you mean is that because they are sharing the same list, when the loop goes through the non-default players, the inserting and appending gets pushed into one single list, instead of like 2 list for 2 non-default player and 3 list for 3 non-default player. Thanks, that brought clarity to my problem.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that I shouldn't initialise it outside the loop to begin with. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a fresh new list for each player... not the same list for all of them; changing the code to

```
     playerDict[name] = [2]
```

should do the trick.

It is important to understand that with Python assignment doesn't copy objects. If you want to make a copy you need to ask explicitly so:

```
a = [2]
b = a
a.append(12)
print(b) # will print [2, 12] because a and b reference the same list object
```

In Python the "list literal" `[2]` isn't indeed a list... but a "list constructor" that creates a new separate list object each time is evaluated.

Comment: Yes, I didn't realise that it doesn't copy objects until it was pointed out. All I was doing was pointing it to the same list. Thank you very much!